# How to handle extensive edits adding code of an external source?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I stumbled over [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4346202) in the queue.

For me it is an radical change, the editor added a huge amount of code from a source linked by the OP, saying: *Links to jsfiddle need to be accompanied by code*

I see the point of directly including linked images, but huge code blocks like this?

How should I handle such suggestions? One problem I see is that I actually would need to check the pasted code, if it's the same linked. Shouldn't the OP decide by himself how much code he wants to show to present his question adequate?

Comment: In this specific case it's absolutely desired behaviour: link-only answers are verboten, so the editor is saving the answer. But yeah, one should check out the JSFiddle and check whether it's the same code

Comment: You're literally not allowed to submit a post with a jsfiddle link and no code - it gives you an error on hitting 'post'. The only reason OP was able to do so is because theres no `http://` or `www.` on the link. For that reason I think the edit is fine.

Comment: Okay, I'm not familiar with js at all. Are there more exceptions? And it's not a "link only answer" it's a question.

Comment: Checking the pasted code is your job as a reviewer. And it's not the OP's choice how much code to put: code **must** be included in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this suggested edit was done is because we don't allow bare links to outside code sources in questions.  The SE software even has some support for this, raising an error if a user tries to post a question containing solely a Fiddle link.

As a moderator, I will occasionally copy the code into the question, largely because people posting questions do not listen to me when I tell them that, yes, the code really does have to be in the actual question.  But I'm not comfortable doing this, because users must agree to [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) when they post their code, and it could be argued that, by putting the code in an outside link, they're bypassing that licensing.

Consequently, unless the question is of Academy Award quality, rather than trying to rescue it, I'm more inclined to just close it as incomplete and reject the suggested edit.

Comment: Just curious: can moderators see if a first attempt to post a question failed? (The lack of `http://` apparently allowed the user to post without code—either accidentally, or on purpose by removing that when a first attempt to post was rejected.)

Comment: No, we don't get access to those stats.